# Second Label not showing up, Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, label

I am trying show the color that is picked with my_label2 but its not showing up. (And im not getting an error message)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

root = Tk()
root.title("Color Picker by Hamza")
root.geometry("400x400")

def color():
    my_color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    my_color2 = colorchooser.askcolor()[1]
    my_label = Label(root, text=my_color).pack(pady=10)
    my_label2 = Label(root, text=my_color2, font=("Helvetica, 32"), bg=my_color).pack()

my_button = Button(root, text="Pick A Color", command=color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thats how it should look like:
[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZxDc.png)

This is how it looks like:
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Aqp.png)

Answer (score 0):

you should write **my_color2**  in label **bg**

try this:-

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import colorchooser

root = Tk()
root.title("Color Picker by Hamza")
root.geometry("400x400")

def color():
    my_color = colorchooser.askcolor()
    my_color2 = my_color[1]
    my_label = Label(root, text=my_color).pack(pady=10)
    my_label2 = Label(root, text=my_color2, font=("Helvetica, 32"), bg=my_color2).pack()

my_button = Button(root, text="Pick A Color", command=color).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ohhhhh i looked everywhere but i forgot to change this, thanks a lot next time i will look more clearly before i write something in the forum, thanks